# Avoiding math mode inside a lstlisting

Tags: math-mode, symbols, listings

I'm using [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) to highlight some PHP code. My problems comes when the code to insert contains the '$' symbol, for example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=PHP]
Select * FROM users WHERE user_name = $_POST['user'];
\end{lstlisting}
```

The $ set maths mode and the text after the lstlisting is included until I type another $. I've been looking for solution but unluckily. Using '`\$`' to escape the symbol $ does not work inside the lstlisting (in my pdf it would appear '`\$`' and obviously I don't want that to happen).

The PHP lst style is set like follows:

```
\lstdefinestyle{PHP}{
 frame=tb, to wrap the text with black horizontal lines
 language=php,
 aboveskip=3mm,
 belowskip=3mm,
 showstringspaces=false,
 basicstyle      = \small\ttfamily,
 keywordstyle    = \color{cyan},
 stringstyle     = \color{gray},
 identifierstyle = \color{blue},
 commentstyle    = \color{green},
 emph            =[1]{php},
 emphstyle       =[1]\color{black},
 emph            =[2]{if,and,or,else},
 breaklines=true,
 breakatwhitespace=true,
 tabsize=3,
 %emphstyle       =[2]\color{dkyellow}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If I prepare a minimal document with your data, I get `$` working as expected, thus not starting math mode.

Comment: But the text after the lstlisting appears to me in green, until I write another $ ("pointing out" that im leaving the match mode?) that comes back to its normal color

Comment: Did you tried to compile the document without the second `$` ? I think it is only the misbeheaving of the editors syntax highlighting. Some editors do not recognize listings well.

Comment: @Rafag Please, make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using TeXnicCenter, and it's only the coloring inside the editor:

This is a [listed bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/texniccenter/bugs/274/).

The issue also effects the `verbatim` environment: http://sourceforge.net/p/texniccenter/bugs/318/.

A "not really nice workaround": if it is really annoying (pages of code colored in a wrong way) you can put this after a wrong `verbatim` or `listing` environment: `\ifx{\verb+$+}!\fi`. It can help when you really need the coloring to be right.

Comment: Thats right, Im using TexnicCenter!

Comment: @Rafag This only effects the coloring. I've added a workaround which doesn't affect the output but fixes the issue. Not a diamond but it can actually help.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a clearer explanation.

"Text after the dollar sign appears in green" means you are talking about the *editor* you use for editing the TeX source. This has nothing to do with TeX math mode.

TeX is a completely separate piece of software from the editor. TeX has absolutely no graphical user interface, but a command line interface instead. Editors run TeX in the background the same way you could if you opened a command prompt and typed `pdflatex myfile.tex`.

The colored stuff you see on the screen is only for your eyes. TeX doesn't care if you edit the source code in Notepad or whatever.

Comment: Finally! I was wondering if any one is going to write this answer or not +1